# Google Maps - Display multiple layers at the same time

Tags: google-maps, traffic

Is it possible to show multiple layers in google maps? For example showing both the transit and traffic layers. I am looking to great a map with multiple layers using rail, bus, car, etc. traffic data to show bottlenecks, hotspots etc.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
{
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4760053,-2.2198102),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 });

 var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
 var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
 trafficLayer.setMap(map); // can only appear to show one label at once?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making one layer transparent...